# Node.js EasyMDE upload image

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the local image upload functionality of the EasyMDE. I couldn't find any working example for Node.js.
Here is my code:

Client side:

```
const easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
  element: document.getElementById('my-text-area'),
  autofocus: true,
  shortcuts: {
    drawTable: "Cmd-Alt-T"
  },
  hideIcons: ['image'],
  showIcons: ["code", "table", "upload-image"],
  uploadImage: true,
  imageUploadEndpoint: "imageUpload",
});
```

Server side:

```
router.post("/imageUpload", async (req, res) => {
  console.log('receiving image...');
});
```

I'm receiving POST request, I insert a breakpoint on the `console.log` row but where do I find the actual image data to save to the disk in the `reg` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `uploadImage: true` and `imageUploadEndpoint` is enough to make the image upload work on the client.

The `req.body` is empty because the image is sent as `form-data` or `multipart/form-data` which ExpressJS does not parse by default.

I've ended up using the `multer` module to process `multipart/form-data` sent by EasyMDE.